# How to set a fixed (or remove) whitespace border around subfloat when using subcaption package

Tags: spacing, subcaption

Say for example I have the following code for a double-column article:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.96\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test/rest_fin.jpg}\hfill
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.96\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test/rest_tex.jpg}\hfill
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test/def_fin.jpg}\hfill
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test/def_rem_fin.jpg}\hfill
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test/def_tex.jpg}\hfill
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test/def_rem_tex.jpg}\hfill
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Worm example}\label{fig:worm}
\end{figure*}
```

Can I control the white border around each image? Either to set it at a fixed number, or remove it completely?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).